# How to turn off all animations on OS X

Tags: macos, animation

Is it possible to turn off all animations on OS X?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

I have only enabled the first four of these, but here are all hidden preferences for disabling animations I have found.

```
# opening and closing windows and popovers
defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false

# smooth scrolling
defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false

# showing and hiding sheets, resizing preference windows, zooming windows
# float 0 doesn't work
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001

# opening and closing Quick Look windows
defaults write -g QLPanelAnimationDuration -float 0

# rubberband scrolling (doesn't affect web views)
defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false

# resizing windows before and after showing the version browser
# also disabled by NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
defaults write -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation -bool false

# showing a toolbar or menu bar in full screen
defaults write -g NSToolbarFullScreenAnimationDuration -float 0

# scrolling column views
defaults write -g NSBrowserColumnAnimationSpeedMultiplier -float 0

# showing the Dock
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0

# showing and hiding Mission Control, command+numbers
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0

# showing and hiding Launchpad
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration -float 0

# changing pages in Launchpad
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration -float 0

# at least AnimateInfoPanes
defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true

# sending messages and opening windows for replies
defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableSendAnimations -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations -bool true
```

Comment: Should I put those lines into `.profile` file? or single time pasting them into terminal will be valid after the reboot?

Comment: This doesn't work any more in Catalina.  Window zooms remain slow animations.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/390990/49582

Comment: `DisableSendAnimations` isn't working for me in Big Sur.

Comment: @alper - no need, the defaults are written to disk.

Comment: What about reacji animations in the Messages app for iMessage?

Answer (score 69):

If you don't want to copy-paste each of the commands shown in the top answer, just select this text, copy-paste it to the terminal and press enter (it will execute all commands at once without having to scroll)

```
defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
defaults write -g QLPanelAnimationDuration -float 0
defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false
defaults write -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation -bool false
defaults write -g NSToolbarFullScreenAnimationDuration -float 0
defaults write -g NSBrowserColumnAnimationSpeedMultiplier -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableSendAnimations -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations -bool true
```

To undo the changes, paste this into the terminal:

```
defaults delete -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled
defaults delete -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled
defaults delete -g NSWindowResizeTime
defaults delete -g QLPanelAnimationDuration
defaults delete -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding
defaults delete -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation
defaults delete -g NSToolbarFullScreenAnimationDuration
defaults delete -g NSBrowserColumnAnimationSpeedMultiplier
defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier
defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-delay
defaults delete com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration
defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration
defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration
defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration
defaults delete com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations
defaults delete com.apple.Mail DisableSendAnimations
defaults delete com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations
```

Mac OS also has dialog boxes, such as the 'Save As'-box (CMD+SHIFT+S) or the 'Print'-box (CMD+P). You can tweak the speed at which all of these boxes appear by using these commands:

Instant:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSWindowResizeTime .001
```

Fast:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSWindowResizeTime .1
```

Default (0.2 seconds):

```
defaults delete NSGlobalDomain NSWindowResizeTime
```

1 = 1 second. To see the difference you have to re-launch an app such as Terminal and summon a dialog box by pressing CMD+S ('Save') for example. You can find more command-line tweaks at [defaults-write.com](http://defaults-write.com)

Answer (score 23):

Animation is *everywhere* in OS X, and it is not possible to disable *all* animation with one global setting, which makes this a very complicated question to answer completely.

I would advise you to try disabling things one at a time as you find animations that annoy you.  Check System Preferences to start.  For example, the Dock magnification animation can be turned off in System Preferences -> Dock.

Also, check out [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html), which allows you to do the following:

- Disable the animation effect when opening files in the Finder
- Disable the animation effect in Mail
- Disable the animation effect in Mission Control
- Disable animation when hiding or showing Dock
- Disable fade-in and fade-out effect,and animation when switching between pages, in Launchpad
- Disable animation in opening windows
- Disable the animation effect when opening information panels or Desktop icons
- Disable the animation effect when selecting information categories
- Accelerate the animation of opening and closing sheets

If there's an animation that really bugs you and you can't figure out how to disable it, try posting a separate question here at Ask Different for that specific issue -- you will get a fast and accurate response.  (And as a nice side effect, both you and the people helping you will earn more rep that way.)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answers above, you can also use [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/). Secrets is an open source PrefPane that lets you set all sorts of hidden options for all sorts of programs on your Mac.

[image: Secrets PrefPane]

**Update**: The main site is down and the project looks to be dead. [Here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/blacktree-secrets/) is the Google Code Archive if you still want to use the vanilla version.

Answer (score 5):

If you're wary of Terminal, [Mountain Tweaks](https://web.archive.org/web/20180825202530/http://tweaksapp.com/app/mountain-tweaks/) is another helpful GUI to turn off, turn on and otherwise tweak the behavior of Lion and Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 4):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142734/7079), wrapped up as a shell script that allows you to toggle between states.

#### examples

```
$ animations_osx.sh 
animations disabled - reboot may be required

$ animations_osx.sh
animations enabled - reboot may be required

$ animations_osx.sh OFF 
animations disabled - reboot may be required

$ animations_osx.sh ON 
animations enabled - reboot may be required
```

#### animations_osx.sh

```
FILE=/tmp/__ez_file_$(date +%s) 

function show_help()
{
  IT=$(CAT <<EOF

  usage: {ON|OFF}

  enables or disables animations in osx. 
  if you don't pass any arguments, it'll toggle between enabled and disabled.

  e.g. 

  ON  => All animations are enabled
  OFF => All animations are disabled
  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi


# returns the opposite of the current state for easy toggling
function getNewState()
{
  defaults read com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration  &> $FILE
  VAL=$(cat $FILE)
  rm $FILE
  if [ "$VAL" == "0" ]
  then
    echo "ON"
  else
    echo "OFF"
  fi
}

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  OP=$(getNewState)
else
  OP=$1
fi

if [ "$OP" == "OFF" ]
then
  defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
  defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false
  defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001
  defaults write -g QLPanelAnimationDuration -float 0
  defaults write -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding -bool false
  defaults write -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation -bool false
  defaults write -g NSToolbarFullScreenAnimationDuration -float 0
  defaults write -g NSBrowserColumnAnimationSpeedMultiplier -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration -float 0
  defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true
  defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableSendAnimations -bool true
  defaults write com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations -bool true
  echo "animations disabled - reboot may be required"
  exit;
fi

if [ "$OP" == "ON" ]
then
  defaults delete -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g NSWindowResizeTime &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g QLPanelAnimationDuration &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g NSScrollViewRubberbanding &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g NSDocumentRevisionsWindowTransformAnimation &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g NSToolbarFullScreenAnimationDuration &> $FILE
  defaults delete -g NSBrowserColumnAnimationSpeedMultiplier &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-delay &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.dock expose-animation-duration &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.Mail DisableSendAnimations &> $FILE
  defaults delete com.apple.Mail DisableReplyAnimations &> $FILE
  rm $FILE
  echo "animations enabled - reboot may be required"
  exit;
fi

show_help
```