# How can I disable Window Minimize animation

Tags: macos, dock

I'm about ready to throttle someone if I can't figure this out.  I have been working  to disable all animation effects throughout OSX (10.9.2).  since I got my new laptop about 3 months ago.  I think I have most of them figured out, but I'm at a loss when it comes to disabling the minimize window application.  The dock gives three options, none of which is acceptable for me.  How can I disable this extremely aggravating behavior?

I'm open to any suggestions, hacks, patches, utilities, or dark magic rituals that will change this behavior.  I'm not interested in people telling me that it can't or shouldn't be done.  This is my personal computer, and I should be able to dictate it's behavior.

Comment: you are mentioning three options, I guess you already discovered the "suck" animation?

Comment: Depending on how geeky (and programming/hacking savvy) you are, you can look into an iPhone jailbreak tweak called "hooks law" which modifies animation timings on iOS and whose developer mentioned on twitter that he ported it to OS X. In it, you could reduce the animation time to zero.

Comment: [Does this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x) doesn't work for you ?, do you want something else ?

Answer (score 36):

While Yosemite doesn't provide an option to prevent the minimise animation, it does provide an option to use the "scale effect", rather than the "genie effect". I find this animation to be much quicker and much less distracting.

See System Preferences -> Dock

[image]

Comment: Such a shame it can't be disabled, really.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/), there is a "Leftclick Orange Window Button" trigger which will allow you to overwrite the default behaviour with a hide action:

[image]

The only downside to this approach is, that if you have multiple windows of the same app open, all of them will be hidden.