# Is there a way to cancel or disable the minimize animation completely?

Tags: macos, mac

Is there a way to cancel or disable the minimize animation completely in Mac OSX?

Comment: which one? all of it ?

Comment: something like this in your Terminal will do it  defaults write com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations -bool true

Comment: @Buscar웃 Thank you you are welcome to link to another answer or leave as response.

Comment: ok read this one http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14001/46541

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manage automatic window animations, use the commands below. **NOTE THAT** you'll have to quit and restart an application for the changes to take effect because it checks these settings on app launch.

***Disable***

To disable automatic window animations, enter the following Terminal command:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO`

***Enable***

To enable window animations:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool YES`

Comment: What version of Mac OSX are you using because I can't seem to get these to work.

Comment: These were from 10.9. I haven't confirmed in 10.10...different company and new role.