# How can i speed up the animation of hiding the menu bar?

Tags: defaults, macos

I recently installed OS X El Capitan and figured out I could hide the menu bar. But it would be nice if i could accelerate the animation. For hiding the dock menu I use these defaults. I wondered whether I can do this for the menu bar?

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 10;
```

How can I get there anyway behind how I can change this in the future for other things? Is there anywhere documentation of adjusting defaults?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.6 there is no preference for controlling the animation speed of the menubar hiding animation. It used to be there, but was removed in Yosemite. The only workaround is to press `Ctrl-Fn-F2` (or `Ctrl-F2` if you inverted the Fn key) to immediately show and activate the menu bar. You can then navigate by keyboard or click items with the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking the manifold `default write` settings found in this question:

[How to turn off all animations on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x)

Answer (score -2):

For me, it seems that this does the trick

```
defaults write com.apple.finder autohide-delay -float 0
killall Finder
```

You can put it all in one command with && or ; to link the two commands if you prefer.

Comment: That didn't work for me :/

Comment: For me neither..

Comment: It would be strange if this would work.

Comment: Seems like this response might be from [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5275#27568) which is more of a question than an answer.

Answer (score -3):

To make your dock animation speed up simply enter this text in the command line:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier -float 0.12;killall Dock
```

To restore the dock animations back to default enter this in Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock autohide-time-modifier;killall Dock
```

For more information click [Here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/28/change-dock-animation-speed-mac-os-x/).

Comment: This answer is regarding the Dock and is not in any way related to the question