# How to turn off Launchpad transparent

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, launchpad, animation

My MacBook, with Retina Display, has problems with smooth animations. How can I turn off the transparency (and blur) in Launchpad on OS X El Capitan?

Also I'd like to turn off animation when I open folders with apps in Launchpad. Is this possible?

Comment: It's confusing what you're trying to say. Can you correct your spelling and language and clarify what exactly you're trying to turn off?

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the following commands in Terminal.app, they will turn off the relevant animations:

```
# showing and hiding Launchpad
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-show-duration -float 0
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-hide-duration -float 0

# changing pages in Launchpad
defaults write com.apple.dock springboard-page-duration -float 0

# restart Dock
killall Dock
```

There are quite a few other animations you can turn off as wel. Take a look at [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63477/98431) answer or you could use [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html)

To turn the animations back on, you enter the same commands, but with `1` instead of `0`