# Disable slow window animation on OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, alfred

I've tried the answers suggested in this question: [How to turn off all animations on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x)

But so far now luck.

When an application has been recently opened, I can switch to it without seeing the window animation. But when an application has not been opened recently, there is still a window animation as it opens.

I use alfred keyboard shortcuts to jump between applications. When I use a keyboard shortcut to jump to an application, not only is there a window animation, but it is in slow-motion (taking about 1-2 seconds to complete).

I am running OS X 10.11.3.

Any ideas I could try beyond this command I have already tried?

```
defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false
```