# How to disable animation on opening Notification Centre in macOS?

Tags: macos, notifications

I couldn't find it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x). Perhaps you can't disable it but if you can I would love to know how.

My preference is for Notification Centre to open instantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Absolutely**, if you are after a snappier mac by saving those precious seconds here and there, I believe the best option is to go into the `System Preferences` and turning on `Reduce Motion` in the `Accessibility` tab.

### Turning on Reduced Motion

[image: System Preferences]
[image: Reduce Motion]

This makes the Notification Centre slide-in animation instant. I hope that helps you out, it really makes a difference. Definitely, let me know how you get on.

Comment: @NikitaVoloboev Perfect! Its a Fantastic little trick hidden away, yet so useful. Happy to share.

Comment: The animation is not really instant. It just changed from sliding to fading, but there still is a noticeable animation. I wonder if there is a way to make it actually instant.