# How to turn off all animations?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, animation

I wish to turn off all animations in macOS. I'm following the steps provided in the answers to [How to turn off all animations on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x).

I wish to turn off animations on my MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 (17D102), but they don't appear to be working. I see no error message or any other message when I run the commands in the terminal. I tried logging out and logging back in but to no effect. How do I troubleshoot this or otherwise find a way to turn off as many animations as possible?

Note:  I tried these 4 commands provided in the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63477/215068) to [How to turn off all animations on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/14001/215068) :

```
# opening and closing windows and popovers
defaults write -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool false

# smooth scrolling
defaults write -g NSScrollAnimationEnabled -bool false

# showing and hiding sheets, resizing preference windows, zooming windows
# float 0 doesn't work
defaults write -g NSWindowResizeTime -float 0.001

# opening and closing Quick Look windows
defaults write -g QLPanelAnimationDuration -float 0
```

Comment: Please provide some details. What answers from the [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x), specifically what commands did you try? What animations specifically are you trying to turn off?

Comment: Have you restarted your computer? Often significant changes to the OS require a restart, not just a logout/login.

Comment: They might have new names on High Sierra?

Comment: How do I look up what the valid names are / what the names might have become?