# How to change Open/Save dialog speed

Tags: finder, performance, macos

Open/Save dialogs on my Mac (macOS 10.14.1) delay about 0.5 to 1 seconds.

How do I change this delay to zero seconds?

Comment: It's super annoying huh.  Animations are not always user-friendly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the speed of the Save/Open dialogs with Terminal. Enter this into Terminal to change the speed to the default:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSWindowResizeTime 0.2
```

Change the number at the end to speed up or slow down the animation. The following is practically instant:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSWindowResizeTime 0.001
```

This is not specific to the open/save dialog however, it reduces the time of all animations on the system that read this value.

- [How to turn off all animations on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x)

Comment: Thank you. I believe the actual issue is that macOS for some reason experience a noticeable latency of actually accessing the disk. Even on a modern machine with SSD.