# How can I disbale login animations in macOS?

Tags: macos, mojave, login, animation

How can I disable the hideously irritating 'rolling cube' animation when logging in?

When I switch from one user account to another, at first it appears to switch instantly to the selected user, but then after entering the password that annoying rolling animation kicks in. 
I would be so happy if I could disable this, as it is not smooth and it's both unnecessary and irritating.

- I tried `defaults write -g userMenuExtraStyle 0` in Terminal, but this did not work, even after reboot. I found this on [how to turn off all animations on OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x). I am using macOS Mojave
- I already have Reduce motion ticked in Accessibility Preferences which reduced desktop switch motion, but not user switch animation. [how can I disable animation when switching desktops in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17929/how-can-i-disable-animation-when-switching-desktops-in-lion)

Is there a way I can disable this animation?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x

Comment: Thanks.. I already have Reduce motion ticked (must have found that whilst searching on here, but thanks anyway) & Thomas; thanx also, but no biscuit I'm afraid; that's the forum where I found the com'd above in T'nal, which didn't work. Unlss there's sum othr command buried in there somewhere.. can't seem to find it... What I find incredible is; these are features which someone has seen fit to add in.. it just seems impossible, incomprehensible to me that this could be done, without some way to undo it.. these animations r such a monumentally bad idea in the first place.. who would DO that?!

Comment: ..also ankiiiii.. it would appear that 'tweak' (for Lion) is supposed to remove animations when switching DESKTOPS, which is a different thing. I already managed to get rid of those animations, but these USER switch animations; thus far I can find no info on.. :-(

Comment: @MafaKinedurtz I have suggested an edit on your question with the updates. Also, use @ for pinging people :). You can ping one person in one comment. Do post an answer when you find one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my MacBook Pro to Sonoma and got this issue. I resolved the issue by replacing the System Settings > Wallpaper & Screen Saver with my own photo