# Artifacts from notification fade-in/out windows when using VNC/Screen-Sharing

Tags: macos, notifications, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I'm using Finder's "Connect to Server" with a "vnc://..." address to access a desktop remotely, from one Mac to another (both running the latest Catalina), and have always had an issue with notification windows (in the upper right corner) that fade-in/fade-out, leaving a "ghost" of the window behind indefinitely.  I can't click on the things behind the windows, and clicking on one of these doesn't do the thing it normally would if the window was fully opaque.  For example, this shows a couple MS Outlook/Update notifications, and an App Store notification.

[image: Ghost Notification Windows]

And here it is with a menu opened up underneath it.  You can only click on a menu item by going in between the gaps of the windows (only the first item is accessible in this example):

[image: With Menu]

I can make them go away temporarily by turning on "DO NOT DISTURB" mode for notifications.  But I'm looking for a way to fix this behavior without disabling notifications.  I don't know yet if this happens with other VNC viewers besides the one built-in to MacOS/Finder.  I can try that out later.  And I'm also planning to try turning off animations if there isn't some other solution out there.  ([How to turn off all animations on OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/how-to-turn-off-all-animations-on-os-x)
)

BTW, This has been happening for me with older versions of MacOS as well.

Comment: Have same issue